# Content Element in Mask: Select instead of Inline

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tx-mask

I'm using latest TYPO3 8.7.7 together with MASK 3.0.1 and would like re-use content Elements.

I've created a two Mask Elements: A Slider- and a Slide-Element. Inside the "Slider" the user can add "Slides". By default theses Content-Element are Inline.

My question is: **Is there a way no to use Inline-Elements and Select-Boxes instead?**

In an Extbase Extesion I would just change the TCA from Inline to Select, but that's not possible in MASK - as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of. But as Mask basically generates native configuration such as TCA and TS you can always export it with the help of the extension [mask_export](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mask_export) and end up with a standalone extension where you can change TCA according to your needs - thus as well switching from IRRE to multiselect. Once done, you can install it in your project as you do with any other extension. You don't need mask on your production instance in that case.